# show div with relative position next to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show a textbox next to another div, but it it appears below instead. The position of the textbox must be absolute. This [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6gk0hybj/) demonstrates the issue. Thank you.

**css**

```
#show{
   border:1px solid gray;
   cursor:pointer;
   float:left; 
}

#textBox{
      display:none;
      position:absolute;
      border:1px solid gray;
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      float:left;
      background-color:pink;
}

#hide{
     clear:left;
     cursor:pointer;
     text-align:center;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id = "show">click me to show test box</div>
<div id = "textBox">text</div>
<div id = "hide">hide text box</div>
```

**js**

```
$('#show').click(function(){
  $('#textBox').show();
});

$('#hide').click(function(){
  $('#textBox').hide();
});
```

Comment: If you need the position of the element to be absolute, just position it where you want it to be and remove the float. Both of the attribute are not needed on the same element. You just have to add a top and left position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most easiest way out would be to replace your css with the below code:

```
#show{
       border:1px solid gray;
       cursor:pointer;
       float:left; 
}
#textBox{
          display:none;
          position:absolute;
          border:1px solid gray;
          width:100px;
          height:100px;
          margin-left:165px;
          background-color:pink;
}
#hide{
         clear:left;
         cursor:pointer;
         text-align:center;
         margin-left:76px;
}
```

Check the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/6gk0hybj/4/

Another method as mentioned is the comments can be found at:http://jsfiddle.net/6gk0hybj/5/

If you want it more dynamic , we need to change a bit of javascript. Let me know if you want it to be more dynamic